# How to call other api using data from one api in react js

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm using axios in react.js application.

I'm calling one API to get access token. I'm calling some other API's when componentWillMount.

I need to pass access token generated from first api call to other api calls.

How can I do this ?

My Code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    if(!isLoggedIn()){
        this.props.actions.token();
    //other api calls
        this.props.actions.getData();
    }       
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You probably would have to save that access token in something like
[localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), then access it whenever you are making another request.

Or, if you are just using it for a single purpose, 
what you probably want is to make another api call after fetching the access token in the promise chain.

```
fetchToken().then((response) => {
  return response.accessToken; // Get access token
}).then((accessToken) => {
  return someOtherApiCall(accessToken); Make another call with the access token
}).then((data) => {
 // Required Data
});
```